# simple mod rewrite

Tags: .htaccess

I'm htaccess stupid and I'm confident this is an easy one for anyone who knows their stuff.

I have several landing pages that are on specific domains. One of the ways I like to track is off the links I use. Users could end up at domain.tld or domain.tld/abcdefg and see the landing page based off the directory.

My question is, how can a user end up at domain.tld/abc or domain.tld/123 and see the same page without actually 301 redirecting to the home page?

I was going to just run an iframe throughout, but I'm not sure how to leave the destination URL alone so it doesn't change to the home page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe what you're looking for is simply this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(123|abc)$ /
```